# Debugging imported Angular library in chrome dev tools

Tags: angular, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, angular-cli

I'm working on an Angular project with angular-cli as the base.  I've imported a library in package.json and I'd like to step through the library in the Chrome dev tools debugger.  How can I make the libraries original typescript source show up in dev tools?  I assume this is related to some webpack configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of the CLI have the "vendorSourceMap" option.

`ng build --vendor-source-map`

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build